# Ignore error on Completable - RxSwift

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

Is there a way to ignore a completable if there is an error ?
For example, I wan't to remove value in my `Firebase Realtime Database`, and delete a picture to `Firebase Storage` when the first completable has finish :

```
// MARK: DELETE - FUNCTION
public func delete(id: String) -> Completable {
    return databaseRef.child("objects").child(id).rx.removeValueAsCompletable()
        .andThen(storageRef.child("objects").child(id).rx.delete())
}
```

The picture may not exists on Storage, so the `delete` function return an error if the child doesn't exist and the Completable of the `delete(id: String)` function return also an error. I wan't to ignore the second function if it returns an error, is it possible ? Does a function named `ignoreOnError()` exists in RxSwift, or something like that ?

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 2):

There is no `ignoreError()`, but you can try to work your way around this with optionals. `Completable.catchError` can work but requires you return another valid `Completable` instead. It's more like "map on error".

If it works for you to just complete on error, then you're all set with `catchError`.

If you need to *not* complete on error, though, I suggest you map this to a  `Observable<Void>` that emits `.next` and `.completed` when the `Completable` source sequence completes. With the power of `.next`, you can map errors to *values* instead of completion.

Let's assume you have a `Observable<Void>` based on your `Completable`:

1. Transform your sequence into a sequence of optionals: `.map(Optional.init)`
2. Transform errors in your sequence into `nil`: `.catchErrorJustReturn(nil)`
3. Return non-nil values, effectively ignoring errors: `.filter { $0 != nil }.map { $0! }` or similar.

If you need a `Completable` in the end but now have a `Observable<Void>`, try to transform it back again: `.concat(.never()).asCompletable()` After all, you know the process so far produces only a single element, an error, or the completion event.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `.catchError { _ in .empty() }`:

```
public func delete(id: String) -> Completable {
     databaseRef.child("objects").child(id).rx.removeValueAsCompletable()
        .andThen(storageRef.child("objects").child(id).rx.delete())
        .catchError { _ in .empty() }
}
```

It transforms error to empty Completable.